# IONIC 3 - platform.ready() triggered slowly

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I had developed Android application in the Ionic framework,

I have used 23 Plugins in my Application

When open the Application , the Platform.ready() state is triggered very lately.

It takes so much of time. How can we improve it ?

Based on that application start time takes 5 to 7 seconds in Android 6.0 and above devices.

I have used below plugins in my config.xml

MySample
    An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.
    Ionic Framework Team

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="^0.7.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-calendar" spec="^5.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="^0.9.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.4.2" />
<plugin name="com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent" spec="^1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^4.0.10" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
<engine name="android" spec="7.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" spec="^2.2.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.2.4" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dreamover-uid" spec="^2.2.4" />

<plugin name="de.applant.cordova.plugin.localnotification" spec="^2.2.4" />
```

Note: 
I had already used the below command

> ionic cordova run android --prod

Comment: Maybe you need to check your native plugins. If you add a sort of crosswalk, then it can be very slow.

Comment: @HyuckKang sorry, I can't understand. Could you explain detaily...

Comment: Could you add your `config.xml`?

Comment: @HyuckKang I had edited my question. Please check it..

Comment: I cannot find specific plugins which cause the issue. I think it is worth to re-create project and build the project each time you add a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try using `ionic cordova run android --prod` cmd to get the apk. When you are normally run it will run using angular development mode that will take time trigger `platform.reddy()`.I think this will help you.

Comment: I had tried that also, after that only 12 seconds of slow reduced into 5 to 7 seconds. But i expect much better performance...

Comment: What are the list of plugins you have used?

Comment: I have edited my question. It has plugins information. Please check it

Comment: I think there is no problem with the plugins you please try removing the platform and adding it again and try the above cmd.